# Does Weblogic 9.2 support Sun Jdk 1.6?

Tags: java, weblogic, compatibility

Does anyone have experience running Weblogic 9.2 on JDK 1.6? I am having trouble finding that information on Oracle site. In the [Supported Configurations](http://e-docs.bea.com/platform/suppconfigs/configs92/92_over/overview.html) page they just mention Sun 32/64bit JDK but I haven't found any references to specific java version.

I would like to upgrade from java 1.5 to 1.6, but we are not quite ready yet to upgrade Weblogic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java 1.5 is the supported version for [WebLogic 9.2](http://e-docs.bea.com/platform/suppconfigs/configs/rhelinux/rhel50_92.html#101911). It looks like 10.0.3 introduced Java 6 for RH AS 5, 64-bit.

[Look here for links](http://e-docs.bea.com/platform/suppconfigs/platform.html) to info about each version of WebLogic. From there, you have to choose your operating system and architecture to find out what JVMs are supported.

Answer (score 3):

Weblogc 9.2.1 - 9.2.3 doesnot support JDK 1.6, any patch/revision of JDK 1.5 will get supported .Latest on today's date is patch 22 of JDK 1.5.